# Explanation of proper procedure to render remote data to grid

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, extjs4.1, coldfusion-9

Can someone please explain to me with sample code on how to properly structure my MVC app? What I want to do is have a grid with a paging toolbar. I want the grid to load 10 records per page. I have setup my ColdFusion server side processing with two SQL statements:

1. Query that gets total record count
2. Query that utilizes the LIMIT arguments set `start` and `limit` respectively.

I find loads of forum questions with local data but my data is on a remote server.

Comment: This question is quite broad. Is there a particular part of this that you want help with?

Answer (score 0):

[Try to read this example in Sencha docs, should help.](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/guide/application_architecture)